# How can I understand symbols used in arguments of methods in Python Documentation?

Tags: python, arguments

I am finding it difficult to understand Python Documentation. So, there are going to be multiple questions in this question.

for e.g.:

```
>>> help(str)
.
.
.

center(self, width, fillchar=' ', /)
    ...

count(...)
    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    ...
.
.
.
```

(1) What does `/` mean in the argument of *center*?

(2) What does `[` and `]` mean in the argument of *count*?

(3) Is `sub[` a single argument (as separated by commas) **or** the whole thing `sub[, start[, end]]` a single argument? Meaning is `, start[, end]` inside the square bracket of `sub` similarly for `start`?

(4) Why are some things defined as just `width` (in *center*) but some with *equal sign* as `fillchar=' '`?

(5) Not related to Python Documentation, but why is `self` not written in the argument of *count*?

*PS: You can also share relevant links for the answers to particular questions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

While declaring arguments, the `/` key means that everything to the left of it must be a *positional argument*, while everything to the right can be a *positional* as well as a *keyword argument*. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) or [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) for more details.

#### Questions 2 and 3

That means the arguments inside the brackets can be provided only if the outer left argument is given. In this case, `sub[, start[, end]]`, `start` can be given only if you have provided `sub`. Similarly, to give `end`, you should provide `sub` and `start` both. Also, the square brackets around the parameters mean that they are optional.

#### Question 4

You can define *default arguments* in Python by assigning them a *default value* using the assignment (=) operator of the form `keywordname=value` in the function declaration. In this case, the `fillchar` argument is optional, so if it is not provided, the function will use `' '` as the `fillchar` value.

#### Question 5

These are called *instance methods*. Instance methods are called by using the syntax `object_name.method_name()`. When calling it this way, the instance method receives the *object* or *instance* as an argument, named `self` by convention. However, `self` should appear in the function definition of `count(...)` (in those three dots).